# Populate Standard Product Field from a Custom Lookup of Product Field

Tags: apex, trigger, before-trigger, product, asset

I'm having a custom Lookup of Product Field on Asset Object .I want that whenever i fill this Field ,it should populate the same with standard lookup of Product Field .Currently i'm using before triggers to Update the Standard Field and i'm even getting the ID in Deug log ..but it's not poulating on record .
Here is Code:

```
private static void updateCustomModelField(list<Asset> lsttriggernew,map<Id,Asset> triggeroldmap)
{
    if(lsttriggernew != null && !lsttriggernew.isEmpty())
    {
        set<id> setProduct = new set<id>();
        list<Asset> lstAsset = new list<Asset>();

        for(Asset objAsset : lsttriggernew)
        {
            if(objAsset.VGA_Model__c != null && (triggeroldmap == null || 
                (triggeroldmap != null && triggeroldmap.get(objAsset.id).VGA_Model__c != objAsset.VGA_Model__c)))
            {
                setProduct.add(objAsset.VGA_Model__c);  
            }  
        }
        if(setProduct != null && !setProduct.isEmpty())
        {
            list<Product2> lstProduct = [select id from Product2 where id in:setProduct];

            if(lstProduct != null && !lstProduct.isEmpty())
            {
                map<id,Product2> mapofProduct = new map<id,Product2>();
                for(Product2 objProduct : lstProduct)
                {
                    if(!mapofProduct.containskey(objProduct.id))
                        mapofProduct.put(objProduct.id,objProduct);
                }
                system.debug('@@@mapofProduct'+mapofProduct);
                if(mapofProduct != null && !mapofProduct.isEmpty())
                {
                    for(Asset objAsset : lsttriggernew)
                    {
                        if(objAsset.VGA_Model__c != null && mapofProduct.containskey(objAsset.VGA_Model__c) 
                            && mapofProduct.get(objAsset.VGA_Model__c) != null)
                        {
                            objAsset.product2 = mapofProduct.get(objAsset.VGA_Model__c);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can achieve what you need in simpler way

```
private static void updateCustomModelField(list<Asset> lsttriggernew,map<Id,Asset> triggeroldmap)
{
    if ( lsttriggernew == null || lsttriggernew.isEmpty() ) 
        return; // It is better to use early exit.

    for(Asset objAsset : lsttriggernew)  {
            if( triggeroldmap == null || triggeroldmap.get(objAsset.id).VGA_Model__c != objAsset.VGA_Model__c )
            {
                objAsset.product2Id = objAsset.VGA_Model__c;
            }  
        }

    }
}
```

Also make sure that you call `updateCustomModelField` in `before` trigger

Comment: `(triggeroldmap == null || triggeroldmap.get(objAsset.id).VGA_Model__c != objAsset.VGA_Model__c)` will suffice.

Comment: yes, I do agree